# Idea behind "[...] makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c

I always wondered why warnings `passing argument 1 from of 'foo' makes pointer from integer without a cast` and alike are only warnings and not errors.

Actually these warnings are almost always errors.

Does somebody know what's the idea behind this?

- Is it mostly to allow prehistoric code to be compiled without errors?
- Or just to comply to the standard? Then latter maybe needs some fixing.

Example:

```
int foo(int *bar)
{
  *bar = 42;
}

void bar()
{
  int n = 0;
  foo(n);      // this is obviously an error
  ...
}
```

Comment: "Why" questions usually can't be answered here, because we aren't the compiler developers.  The diagnostic text you quote sounds like a GCC diagnostic, so you might have better luck asking this question on the mailing list `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` (see https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html).

Comment: What compiler are you using? This is an error unless doing `fpermissive`

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu https://www.godbolt.org/z/2gDqxv : gcc treats this as a warning: https://www.godbolt.org/z/2gDqxv

Comment: @zwol gcc, clang, MS C compiler all give similar warnings. And it's not specific to gcc at all.

Comment: Oh, my bad,  I compiled using g++ not gcc.

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu yep, the behaviour of C++ is definitely more sane than that of c

Comment: This behaviour is present in the standard, and it is implementation defined: "... An integer may be converted to any pointer type ...". http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.2.3.html

Comment: @Jose The document is misleading. You need an explicit conversion (cast) for this.

Comment: @Jose: As n.m. said, that document is non-authoritative and misleading. If you want to make claims like this cite the standard, not sketchy sites like coding-guidelines or cppreference.

Comment: A warning is a diagnostic. The standard only requires a diagnostic.

Comment: @zwol: The fact that people here are not the originators of knowledge does not mean that they do not possess or cannot acquire the knowledge. There are more ways of learning than direct experience. And are you sure none of the people here are the compiler developers?

Comment: @Persixty I have no idea what *any* of this means.

Comment: @n.m. Read the answer by R. below in context with http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf. As well as section 3.4.3 (Undefined Behaviour). In the page you referenced it only talks about converting 0 to a pointer. Also look at my comment on R.'s answer below.
There's no question my answer and R.'s answer and other comments above are in 'Language Lawyer' mode and offering a formal interpretation of the formal language specification!  My link is the last draft available in Public Domain.

Comment: @Persixty I don't recall referencing any page here. I was going to post an answer but R. has posted almost exactly the same thing I wanted to.

Comment: @n.m. On account of me being an idiot and sending you a comment that should have gone to Jose! I apologise.

Comment: @Jose It's undefined behaviour. However one of the things the standard permits is a locally defined interpretation (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic). In short compiling that code amounts to supporting a language extension (beyond behaviour fully defined in the standard). The only arithmetic value the page you cite defines a meaning for is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does somebody know what's the idea behind this?
>
> - Is it mostly to allow prehistoric code to be compiled without errors?
> - Or just to comply to the standard? Then latter maybe needs some fixing.

It is to comply with the standard in the sense that the standard requires conforming implementations to diagnose such issues, as @R.. describes in his answer.  Implementations are *not* required to reject programs on account of such issues, however.  As for why some compilers instead accept such programs, that would need to be evaluated on a per-implementation basis, but this quotation from the first edition of K&R may shed a bit of light:

> **5.6 Pointers are not Integers**
>
> You may notice in older C programs a rather cavalier attitude toward
>   copying pointers.  It has generally been true that on most machines a
>   pointer may be assigned to an integer and back again; no scaling or
>   conversion takes place, and no bits are lost.  Regrettably, this has
>   led to the taking of liberties with routines that return pointers
>   which are then merely passed to other routines -- the requisite
>   pointer declarations are often left out.

(Kernighan & Ritchie, *The C Programming Language*, 1<sup>st</sup> ed., 1978)

Notice in the first place that this long predates even C89.  I'm a bit amused today that the authors were *then* talking about "older" C programs.  But note too that even at that time, the C language as defined by K&R did not formally permit implicit conversion between pointers and integers (though it did permit casting between them).

Nevertheless, there were programs that relied on implicit conversion anyway, apparently because it happened to work on the targeted implementations.  It was attractive, by some people's standards at the time, in conjunction with primordial C's implicit typing rules.  One could let a variable or function intended to return or store a pointer default to type `int` by omitting its declaration altogether, and as long as it was interpreted as a pointer wherever it ultimately was used, everything usually happened to work as intended.

I'm inclined to guess that everything continuing to work as intended, thereby supporting backwards compatibility, was a consideration for compiler developers in continuing to accept implicit conversions, so that's "allow[ing] prehistoric code to be compiled."  I note, however, that these days code with implicit conversions of this kind are much less likely to work as intended than they used to be, for many machines these days have 64-bit pointers but only 32-bit `int`s.

Answer (score 7):

Per *6.5.2.2 Function Calls*, ¶ 7:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type

The relevant text in *6.5.16.1 Simple Assignment* is:

> Constraints
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has arithmetic type;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer constant; or
> - the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool, and the right is a pointer.

None of these allow the left operand as a pointer and the right operand as an integer. Thus, such an assignment (and by the first quoted text above, the function call) is a **constraint violation**. This means the compiler is required by the standard to "diagnose" it. However it's up to the compiler what it does beyond that. Yes, an error would be highly preferable, but just printing a warning is a low-quality way to satisfy the requirement to "diagnose" constraint violations like this.

Comment: May be helpful to add the footnote in 6.3.2.3:  The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.

That only applies to well-formed conversions but by an assumption of sanity I'd say there's nothing else a compiler that chooses to compile that code could reasonably do!

Comment: @Persixty: Sanity went out of fashion years ago.  If a 32-bit compiler is given something like `unsigned mul(unsigned short x, unsigned short y) { return x*y;}` it may seem like the only sane things for it to do if `x*y` exceeds `INT_MAX` would be to either trap or yield the arithmetical value of the product (according to the Rationale, the authors of the Standard expected most compilers to do the latter) but gcc is more "creative"; invoking that function with `x*y > INT_MAX` may disrupt the behavior of the surrounding code.

Comment: I take the point though C11 says that's non-compliant "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."
My point is that having detected the ill-formed code and decided to issue a warning and emit code (rather than error) the implementer has created a language extension and should document the behaviour.

Comment: @Persixty: They're not unsigned operands. `unsigned short` promotes to `int` via default promotions, *then* the multiplication takes place.

Comment: @R.. Ouch! Fair play. The operands converted to `int` (if range compatible - typically so) and then the (logical) result is outside `int` range (also typically possible) results in UB. To me the sanity was lost when unsigned types are converted to `int` in preference to unsigned. But that is the standard. It's also perverse that arithmetic overflow is UB rather than an implementation defined value. Perverse or not, that is what the standard says. It should definitely be on lists of 'little known gotchas'. Got me anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of assigning an arithmetic type to a pointer is not well formed in the C standard. (See the answer provided by R.. for relevant sections.)

Your compiler (or the settings you're using) have decided to treat that as a warning.

Compilers have default settings and often support language extensions and those may be quite liberal.

Notice for anything outside the language specification it's up to the implementers of the compiler to decide what's an error or if they're going to interpret it as a language extension and (hopefully) issue a warning that the the code is off the offical piste.

I agree that's not best. My recommendation would be to treat is an error because it almost certainly is and casting an `int` to a pointer is the standard supported way of being explicit and getting the same result (e.g. `int *`n).

I think you're using GCC and it's notorious for "helpfully" compiling things that it could better serve you by rejecting and making you use standard constructs.

Enable all warnings (`-Wall` on the gcc command-line) and make sure you understand and address them all appropriately.

Comment: Yes, of course I use `-Wall` precisely for that reason.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's compilers being helpful when they're not! If the out of the box settings were more conservative generations of novice programmers would be led away from pointlessly bad habits.

Comment: Totally agree on this.

Comment: @Jabberwocky If you value your sanity, use `-Werror`.